# PCL compilation error LNK2019

Tags: command-line, compilation, point-cloud-library

I'm currently trying to build PCL so that i can use RTABmaps 
I ran into some issues while trying to build the PCL 1.7.2 using the command line to configure it and then build it. I'm using CMake 3.9 and Visual Studios 10 2010 to build the PCL from source. I have already downloaded the dependencies from pointclouds.org/downloads/windows.html and followed the instructions at https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/wiki/Installation#windows to build the PCL from source.

The build failed and the following errors were shown: 
 [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhbR4.png)

The following are the directories that are in the Path:

C:\Users\qlin\Desktop\RTABmap compilation\pcl-pcl-1.7.2\build\bin;

C:\Program Files\zlib\bin;

C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;

I thought it could be because of the version so i tried anoher version :PCL 1.8. However the same results happened.

I did some research on the error LNK2019 and it says that the linker can't find a matching definition for an external symbol in any of the link files. I saw the tutorial that shows how to build it from source using the CMake Gui but am not ableto solve the problems.

I did some more research and found that this issue has been solved before but the answer to it is too vague for me to understand. it says that there was a mismatch error in between PCL 1.8.0 and 1.6.0 ,and the mismatch was in choosing the Dependencies version of Boost, eigen, flann, OpenNI and VTK 5.8.0. 
How do i resolve this error

I hope someone could help me

Answer (score 0):

The all-in-one installer found here makes building PCL a much easier process.
http://unanancyowen.com/en/pcl18/